# Could not draw an image onto canvas

Tags: javascript, html

i have an image in an HTML tag

---

```
<img id="enemy" src="img/enemy.png" style="display: none;">
```

---

which I'm then getting by Id into a variable, like always, and then drawing via

---

```
canvasContext.drawImage(enemy, enemyX, enemyY);
```

---

I have already set up the canvas and its context('2d') and it works in everything I throw at it, but I cannot draw there the image above. I get the error

---

> TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.

---

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478564/error-when-drawing-canvas-picture-from-base-64-string You can see the answer here.

Comment: Can we see the code by which you're "getting by Id into a variable?"

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("enemy");
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
```

myCanvas in your canvas. maybe you do not get your image element in javascript.

Comment: I do get it, and it draws everything else without any problem. as you see above, canvasContext calls the function drawImage as you suggested but I still get that error

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself, it's pretty confusing because I have found out that the problem persists in all the browsers and only works if `getElementById` is stated just after `canvasContext`, but I can accept it.
Otherwise the image on JavaScript should be constructed as

---

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "folder/image.png";
```

---

without having to append the image onto HTML.